# Xcode 4.5 not detecting iOS sdk 6.1

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.5

I have just updated my device sdk to 6.1 beta version. I have been using Xcode 4.5, earlier it was detecting the device in 6.0.1 but now there is no detection. Please help.

Comment: In the future, you can just update Xcode -- it comes with the new version of iOS.

Comment: How can I do that as I have an Indian i.d and it is not getting updated through the Mac?

Comment: Just go to the Mac App Store and check your updates tab.

Comment: I have just edited my comment..please read it..

Comment: You can see an update in the Mac App Store for Indian ids as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you'll need to update to Xcode 4.6 which has iOS 6.1 support

Comment: I was actually thinking of downgrading my device OS. Do you have any idea how to change it back to 6.0.1?

Comment: I dont think you can downgrade without jailbreaking

Comment: Xcode4.6 requires 10.8. Still there is bug with Xcode 4.5.2, as the same thing is happening to me.The trick is disconnect your device and restart XCode and connect it.Xcode detects the device automatically.

Comment: @AjaySharma That is simply not true, I am running Xcode 4.6 on Lion

Answer (score 2):

You need to download a [Xcode 4.6](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/index.php)

Answer (score 2):

Also instead of updating your XCode, you can ask any other buddy to send you the SDK: `iPhoneOS6.1.sdk` & `iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk`. Just Restart XCODE now :)

Comment: Nice reply thanks but i have already downloaded Xcode 4.6 ..still +1 for your effort..

Answer (score 0):

put the sdk at the directory：

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer‌​/SDKs/